# Code conversion (c# to c++)

Tags: c#, c++

How to convert the following code into c++?

1st part:

```
    public static void ReadPoints(string aFile, Point2D [] pArray)
    {
        try
        {
            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(aFile))
            {
                sr.BaseStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
                for(int i=0;i<pArray.Length;i++)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    int index = line.IndexOf("\t");
                    pArray[i].X = double.Parse(line.Substring(0,index));
                    pArray[i].Y = double.Parse(line.Substring(index+1,line.Length-(index+1)));
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Warning: An exception has been thrown at ReadPoints()!");
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
```

---

2nd part：

```
    public static int ReadInt(string prompt)
    {
        int anInt = 0;
        bool wrongInput;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                anInt = Int32.Parse(line);
                wrongInput = false;
            }
            catch(FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input!!!");
                wrongInput = true;
            }
        }
        while(wrongInput);
        return anInt;
```

### }

The code followed is the definition of class Point2D. The code above is used to read the coordinate of points and read int from the string.

```
class Point2D
{
public:
    double get_x();
    void set_x(double value);
    double get_y();
    void set_y(double value);

private:
    double x;
    double y;
};

double Point2D::get_x()
{
    return x;
}
void Point2D::set_x(double value)
{
    x = value;
}
double Point2D::get_y()
{
    return y;
}
void Point2D::set_y(double value)
{
    y = value;
}
```

Comment: [Try](http://cscpp.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

For your first part, reasonably idiomatic C++ would look something like this:

```
struct Point2D { 
    double x, y; // pass-through get/set pair gained nothing over public data.

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Point2D &p) { 
        return is >> p.x >> p.y;
    }    
};
```

Yes, this has public data -- and that's *generally* not a great idea. In this case, however, it's probably not a terrible idea--and it's *effectively* what your code with private data and a purely pass-through get/set pair accomplished anyway. If there are really some invariants the class could/should enforce, I'm all for making the data private and enforcing them, but if you're not going to enforce invariants, making the data private and adding a get/set pair just adds syntactic noise, not utility. To use this to read some data from a file, you could do something like this:

```
std::ifstream infile(aFile);
std::vector<Point2D> points{std::istream_iterator<Point2D>(infile),
                            std::istream_iterator<Point2D>()};
```

This isn't really equivalent to `ReadPoints` by itself though -- it's more like `ReadPoints` *plus* whatever code you currently have calling `ReadPoints` to create and fill an array with points from the file. That is to say, this creates a `vector` named `points`, and fills it with points that it reads from the file with the name in `aFile`.

As far as reading an `int` goes, if I really needed to assure that (for example) the user has only entered digits, I'd probably do something like this:

```
bool is_int(std::string const &in) {
    // technically `-` isn't a digit, but we want to allow it.
    static const std::string digits{ "-0123456789" };
    return in.find_first_not_of(digits) == std::string::npos;
}

int readint(std::string const &prompt) {
    std::string input;
    do {
        std::cout << prompt;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
    } while (!is_int(input) && std::cout << "Bad input (non-digit entered)\n");
    return stoi(input);
}
```

At the moment, this doesn't enforce the `-` being at the beginning of a number, so it would allow input like `3-2`. If you need to ensure against such things (and possibly the number being in range) you'd need to rewrite `is_int` a bit to enforce exactly what you want.